# JFrog Artifactory support for OSGi-Bundles & Tycho-Plugin

Tags: java, osgi, artifactory, tycho

## *My task:*

I am in the process of migrating our repositories hosted on premise Nexus to JFrog Artifactory and i am stuck at support for OSGi-bundles (upload and dependency-resolution).

## *Current situation:*

Currently we develop, build, deploy and consume our own OSGi-bundles via Nexus. The OSGi-bundle gets built and deployed (with Maven and Tycho) to Nexus as ZIP/JAR. On Nexus we use a plugin ([Tycho/Nexus Unzip Plugin](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Tycho/Nexus_Unzip_Plugin)) that mirrors and unzips the OSGi-bundles and makes them available as a virtual repository. This enables Maven with the Tycho-plugin to resolve dependencies when consuming those OSGi-bundles.

A example structure in the SNAPSHOT repository on Nexus:

```
+- Snapshots
 +--- A0
  +--- A1
   +--- A2
    +--- 1.*.*-SNAPSHOT
    |+-- A2-1.*.*.zip
    |+-- A2-1.*.*.pom
    |+-- A2-1.*.*-p2artifacts.xml
    |+-- A2-1.*.*-p2metadata.xml
```

And the corresponding structure generated by Tycho/Nexus Unzip Plugin on Nexus:

```
+- Snapshots-Unzip for P2
 +--- A0
  +--- A1
   +--- A2
    +--- 1.*.*-SNAPSHOT
     +--- A2-1.*.*-SNAPSHOT.zip-unzip
     |+-- features
     |+-- plugins
     |+-- artifacts.jar
     |+-- artifacts.xml.xz
     |+-- content.jar
     |+-- content.xml.xz
     |+-- p2.index
```

The dependency (A2 in this case) is included in the *.target.target file by pointing to the location of the unzip-repository: [http://*****:****/nexus/service/local/repositories/Snapshot-Unzip/content/A0/A1/A2/1.*.*-SNAPSHOT/A2-1.*.*-SNAPSHOT.zip-unzip](https://stackoverflow.com)

## *My problem:*

There seems to be no solution to implicitly or explicitly provide the deployed OSGi-bundles unziped as Nexus with the Tycho/Nexus Unzip Plugin does on JFrog Artifactory.

## *My research and attempts:*

Official documentations of JFrog Artifactory suggest that there is explicit support for P2-repositories ([P2-repositories](https://jfrog.com/help/r/jfrog-artifactory-documentation/p2-repositories)). However when attempting to replicate the steps the results were not what I was expecting.

- We do not have one OSGi-bundle but multiple with multiple versions (SNAPSHOT & RELEASE) in each corresponding repository
- When creating a virtual P2-repository and trying to include a local repository (where our OSGi-bundles reside) I have to point to the metadata directly and cannot include a whole repository
- Also when pointing to the metadata which resides in a ZIP, the documentation suggests to finish the subpath/URL with '!'. This however does nothing and dependency resolution during build process fails

## *My expectations:*

The current use-case is something that was implemented long before I started working and needs to be supported for existing applications. I cannot change the way the applications depend and resolve OSGi-bundles. I "just" need to replicate the current behavior of Nexus in JFrog Artifactory (ideally).

Is there a approach I could try or some implementation detail in JFrog Artifactory that I missed?
Thanks!

Comment: Consider switching to the new way of creating Maven p2 sites that can be consumed directly: https://github.com/eclipse-tycho/tycho/blob/master/RELEASE_NOTES.md#creating-maven-p2-sites-with-tycho-packaging

Comment: Thanks for your advice however our project is currently using Tycho v2.7.5 and I don't know if I can upgrade without any sideeffects (old versions no longer building).

I will have to look into your approach if I can update Tycho.

Comment: For upgrading from 2.x to 4.x see [Migration guide 2.x -> 3.x](https://github.com/eclipse-tycho/tycho/blob/master/RELEASE_NOTES.md#migration-guide-2x---3x) and [Migration guide 3.x > 4.x](https://github.com/eclipse-tycho/tycho/blob/master/RELEASE_NOTES.md#migration-guide-3x--4x).